# PHP header not loading

Tags: php, .htaccess, header

Hello guys I'm having a problem with something in php.

I made a rule in .htacess RewriteRule sig.jpg test.php [L,R=301]

to open test.php when sig.jpg is loaded, so I added on my test.php the following code :

```
<?
    if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
        header("Location: sig.png");
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.facebook.com/123423vote ");
    }
?>
```

so this would change .jpg file for .png file

if you check [my domain](http://%20gabrielamello.com/sig.jpg)  it will redirect you to sig.png in another directory.

but my problem is : when I add

```
<img src="http://www.gabrielamello.com/sig.jpg" title="test" alt="test" />
```

it's not showing the png file.

someone could help me please?

thanks

Comment: Have you looked at your developer tool's network inspector what the request for the image results in?

Comment: when I load it in a forum via bbcode it shows correctly, but on my homepage it shows nothing, I looked at network tools inspector and it even load, when I access it via direct link it shows correctly, but when I add it to a image code it not load like direct, I'm not sure what is happening, I already tried to change the location to full page address but nothing change.

Comment: try `header("Location: /sig.png”);`

Comment: Hello Jarod,
no it's not working. when I tried your change, direct link stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Because you explicitly tell your script not to load an image (but a facebook page) when loaded from inside of an `<img>`-tag.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the `HTTP_REFERER` check but I know that the direct request has no `HTTP_REFERER` but the `<img>`-tag request does.

Try with:

```
<?php
header("Location: sig.png"); 
?>
```

This should always show the image. Then slowly add the rest of the script.

Developer tools networking tab shows the request headers.